# location of log file (sysout.log) of IBM Websphere

Tags: websphere

Where is the log file(sysout.log) of Websphere application  server created??I am using Rational software architect.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[WAS_HOME]\profiles\[PROFILE_NAME]\logs\[SERVER_NAME]\

Answer (score 0):

Right click to server, properties... click Websphere Application Server form left menu

[image: webSphere log location]