# where does System.out.println statements gets printed in websphere App Server

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, log4j, websphere, websphere-6

I have an application which is configured on `IBM WebSphere 6.0` version.

1. In that application, where ever the `System.out.printlN()` Statements, are there
   Where do they get printed? 
   I mean which log files, will get it printed?
   In standalone I can check in the console, that application is deployed in windows server box
2. How to Identify where all the log.debug, log.info statements get printed from the application into the server box.
   I tried checking in `log4j.properties`, but didnot find any useful info about that.

Background, we have a Websphere app server, where we have configured 2 Nodes and I am deploying in the Node 01, on my changes and trying to debug, but no help.

Please guide if any one has past exp on it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2988375/location-of-log-file-sysout-log-of-ibm-websphere/3065240#3065240

Answer (score 2):

I haven't been using WebSphere 6 lately. I newer versions you have a profile directory and a log directory within where the log file reside.

The second option is to go into the WAS administration console and go to "Troubleshooting > Logs and Trace > server_name " there you can directly view the logs. This way is documented for [WAS 6.0](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v6r0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.websphere.express.doc%2Finfo%2Fexp%2Fae%2Futrb_logtrace.html) as well.

Comment: Will the admin console also show you the location of the files? I believe it does in current versions.

Comment: Actually I can't tell. We don't run that old versions anymore.

Answer (score 1):

As others have hinted, by default the `SystemOut.log` and `SystemErr.log` files are located in each node's `profiles/<profileName>/<serverName>/logs` directory. (These locations and file names can be overridden in the Administration Console.)

log4j logs will depend on the appenders in your log4j configuration (could be a log4j.properties or a log4j.xml file), but might also be affected by whether anything in your application uses Jakarta Commons Logging. If it does, [you may find all log4j logging also going to SystemOut.log](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8131529/websphere-all-logs-are-going-to-systemout-log/).

Comment: Ahh, good point @UdoHeld. It's been so long that if that's true, I don't remember it.

Answer (score -2):

It should get logged in Program files/IBM/SDP/profiles/runtimes/baseV6...

something like this .currently am at home and I don't have exact path.But search in profile directory .

You should always define your own path for appenders in your applications logging.xml instead of using default path of WAS.

Answer (score -3):

The log files are resided at C:\Program Files\IBM\SDP\runtimes\base_v7\profiles\was70profile1\logs\server1