# Application is responding with 500 if java process run for more than 1 min at Websphere

Tags: timeout, websphere, internal-server-error

I have simple Spring J2EE web application application hosted on Websphere in test environment. We have some stored procedures which takes more than 1 min sometimes. In such scenario, server is returning `500 Internal server error page`while firing ajax call. If total response time is less than 1 min it works fine.

When we run same application on our local on tomcat server, it goes not throw 500, instead returns response even if our code takes more that 2 minutes. But it fails on Websphere server.

I have tested by adding sleep in both servers tomcat at local and Websphere on Test environment, it fails at Test environment. It seems there is some timeout setting on websphere.

I also tried adding following custom properties in web container setting under application server:

1. ConnectionIdleTimeout (300)
2. ConnectionIOTimeOut(300)
3. ConnectionKeepAliveTimeout

Below is content of html I am getting:

```
   <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">↵<html><head>↵<title>500 Internal Server Error</title>↵</head><body>↵<h1>Internal Server Error</h1>↵<p>The server encountered an internal error or↵misconfiguration and was unable to complete↵your request.</p>↵<p>Please contact the server administrator,↵ you@your.address and inform them of the time the error occurred,↵and anything you might have done that may have↵caused the error.</p>↵<p>More information about this error may be available↵in the server error log.</p>↵</body></html>
```

Comment: what do you see on server logs when you receive the error? It shall indicate if problem is a socket issue or something like a transaction timeout.

Comment: Thanks for input l will look into same. When you say server input which file will have these timeout logs

Comment: SystemOut.log and SystemErr.log files would be a good place to start. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2988375/location-of-log-file-sysout-log-of-ibm-websphere).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This problem is fixed by increasing the ServerIOTimeout in plugin-cfg.xml .

ServerIOTimeout means "how long should the plug-in wait for a response from the application" in seconds. After the socket is opened, the plug-in sends the request to the Application Server. Its default value is 60 in Websphere 7 which is very less for some cases.
Important point to not is , once you edit plugin-cfg.xml. You need to regenerate plugin for change to take effect. And other thing is that even if you change it in admin console, it reads it from plugin-cfg.xml if it is present there, so always directly change the xml file.

Location for this file :-

For details,refer [IBM DOCS](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21318463) and [this really good blog](http://javagongura.blogspot.in/2013/01/serveriotimeout-property-in-ihs-plugin.html).